# Enable virtualization on your computer

Tags: docker, виртуализация, hyper-v

Всем привет.

Никак не могу запустить докер на моей машине.
Выдаёт такую ошибку:
[image: Ошибка докера]

Примечательно то, что виртуализация в биосе включена и в диспетчере задач пишет что виртуализация включена.
Единственное что смущает так это "Преобразование адресов второго уровня", якобы без этого не  запустить виртуальные машины и тп.

[image: Консоль]

Но мой проц. ведь поддерживает виртуализацию.

Неужели мне придётся покупать новое железо ради запуска докера

Comment: А у вас DEP точно включено? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-enable-dep-options-mine-are-grey-and-i-cant/2663dc18-72de-4729-b9ef-de398a7ca756

Comment: @ExplodingKitten да, оно включено

Comment: поройтесь в биосе еще, лет 20 таких вопросов не видно.

Comment: и было бы более полезным дать характеристики материнки и проца.

Comment: ммм, извиняюсь. трансляцю ядресов вроде встречается уже в самом виртуальном окружении. в virtualbox это точно есть.

Comment: У вас Hyper-V включен? Что пишет команда `(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online).State`?

Comment: @nexoma Мат.плата ASUS p5q-vm, проц: Intel core 2 quad 9400

Comment: @PakUula ваша команда не работает, а так могу сказать что Hyper-V включен что в биосе, что через сам Windows

Comment: вот  Pak Uula правильно заметил, поищите статейки по  SLAT windows10 hyper-v  типа такой https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1401.hyper-v-list-of-slat-capable-cpus-for-hosts.aspx (даже винда может ограничивать)   И проц старенький, посоветовал бы еще 2 варианта. попробовать с virtualbox (должно также не получиться), ну и линукс поставить, если опыт есть.

Comment: УВЫ, https://superuser.com/questions/643126/how-can-i-tell-if-my-intel-core-cpu-supports-slat

Comment: Как я и говорил...
Какой ужас, просто одно разочарование

Comment: попробуйте линукс!